# IOS Float Not Being Sent Through POST Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am have been trying to send a post request from one of my `ViewControllers` which collects some data from another `ViewController` through

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

Anyways when I try to send the post request to send variables to the database, the last two parameter values are stored as 0. I have already converted the float variables to to `NSStrings`. I checked to make sure the values were correct before sending the post request through `NSLog`. However it is still showing up as zero. When I enter the form manually through my web browser with the exact same values, they are stored in the database.

My Post request looks like the following:

```
NSString *dateString = _date.text;
NSString *times = _time.text;
NSString *shape_illuminated = _shape.text;
NSString *orientation_illuminatedString = _orientation.text;
NSLog(@"compass is:%@%@", compassReceived, rollReceived);

NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/mobile_app/submit.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString * params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"date=%@&time=%@&shape_illuminated=%@&orientation_illuminated=%@&=compass_direction=%@&=degreehorizon=%@", dateString, times, shape_illuminated, orientation_illuminatedString, compassReceived, rollReceived];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                       NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                       if(error == nil)
                                                       {
                                                           NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                           NSLog(@"HttpReponseData = %@",text);
                                                           NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];



                                                               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Account error"
                                                                                                               message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dictionary]
                                                                                                              delegate:nil
                                                                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                               [alert show];

                                                       }

                                                   }];
[dataTask resume];
```

Some of the values from those NSLogs are:

> compass is:127.0Angle:99.485866

In mysql I have the fields set up as floats.

Any ideas?

UPADATE:
I tried hard coding the values for compass_direction and degreehorizon and it still did not work.

UPDATE:
I have now tried properly configuring the url parameters using the following method:

```
-(NSString *)urlenc:(NSString *)val
{
    CFStringRef safeString =
    CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                            (CFStringRef)val,
                                            NULL,
                                            CFSTR("/%&=?$#+-~@<>|,.()[]{}^!"),
                                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", safeString];
}
```

and then adding:

```
SString *query =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"shape_illuminated=%@&orientation_illuminated=%@&=compass_direction=%@&=degreehorizon=%@",
     [self urlenc:shape_illuminated],
     [self urlenc:orientation_illuminatedString],
     [self urlenc:convertedCompass],
     [self urlenc:convertedRoll]];
     NSLog(@"%@", query);
     [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content- type"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[query dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

but those two values are still not being sent. The output from the nslog looks fine to me. I even made a php form and entered the same values on my computer which works great, so I do not know what is going on here.

Comment: Did you checked the exactly values that you receiving in the server side?

Comment: on the server side I am receiving 0 for the compass and angle when sending from app.

Comment: The problem I think is with this line: `NSString * params = [NSString stringWithFormat:...compass_direction=%@&=....orientation_illuminatedString, compassReceived, rollReceived];`, which you are using `%@` but you have to use `%f` because it is float as you said.

Comment: still no go, and I already converted the floats to strings.

Comment: Ok maybe the problem is that you don't have your parameters url encoded. Can you try to make url encoded all parameters before you added in the httpBody?

Comment: You are not setting the Content-Type of the POST. You need to set the a Content-Type header field to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: Okay I just added that and still nothing.

Comment: Might I suggest AFNetworking?

Comment: AfNetworking is a bit much, I just added the content type header and still it is not working. It is weird. Everything else gets posted to the database just not the last two parameters.